# PHP cURL Scroll

Tags: php, rolamento, libcurl

Olá, preciso pegar dados de um site que o mesmo um scroll FINITO! porém, é dividido em partes, eu tenho que dar scroll ai carrega o resto, tem como eu pegar a página total ? ou tem outra função ou biblioteca que me indicam ?

obrigado!

Comment: O cURL faz uma requisição, vc deveria ver qual requisição ele faz quando alcança o fim da página no scroll e fazer essa mesma requisição... Agora, você poderia programar um browser para fazer o scroll infinito com o Selenium.

Comment: como eu vejo essa requisição ? e o que é esse Selenium que eu não entendi direito ? poderia me passar seu contato Paulo ?

Comment: Eu uso uma técnica pra ver a requisição: No Firebug, abra a aba Network e vc verá todas as requisições feitas. Clique com o botão direito na requisição e vc tem a opção de copiar o comando Curl prontinho. Esse assunto é bem complexo. Procure sobre Web Crawlers, Selenium. Se vc entende inglês, um livro bom é Webbots, Spiders and Screen Scrapers, vc deve achar para download